# Round up numbers such as 1.23 to 2 in Python

Tags: python, rounding

Please tell me how to round up numbers in Python.

If I have 1.47, how to round it up to 2 ? 
Or if I have 10.13, how to round it up to 11?

The answer is correct with `round(round(1.47, 1))`, but is there another way to round up such numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function for that in the `math` module called `ceil`.

```
>>> import math
>>> print math.ceil(1.47)
2.0
```

If you want an integer,

```
>>> import math
>>> print int(math.ceil(1.47))
2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Obviously use `math.ceil`, but here's a fun alternative anyway:

```
>>> [-(-x//1) for x in 1.47, 10.13, 2.0]
[2.0, 11.0, 2.0]
```

And an even shorter/funnier one:

```
>>> [0--x//1 for x in 1.47, 10.13, 2.0]
[2.0, 11.0, 2.0]
```

Or `--0-- x//1`, see @MarkDickinson's comment below.

Apply `int(...)` if you want an `int`, I'll just keep these as they are to showcase "integer division for floats" and to keep it visible what's happening.

Comment: wrap results in int, seems like it's what OP wants

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned it now.

Comment: I like to write the second example as `[--0-- x//1 for x in 1.47, 10.13, 2.0]`: `--0--` is the "ceiling division operator", which converts a subsequent floor division to do ceiling division instead. (Yes, technically `0--` works just as well, but `--0--` looks so much better.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ha, I googled "ceiling division operator" to see how popular it is, got three results, and the first is [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299093/how-to-perform-ceiling-division-in-integer-arithmetic/33299457#comment54417923_33299093) referring to my own earlier answer. So **that's** why this felt so familiar :-).  I like your way and how you're thinking of it. I also still like mine, though, for the symmetry (x being in the middle of two "double operators" and the numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `math` ceiling function, namely `ceil`:

```
import math
print math.ceil(1.47)
```

will yield `2.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215406/5827958