# is there a faster way to go through a very large lists?

Tags: python

My goal is to create a function that takes a list as an input and change that list in such way that `sum(list)` will be the smallest value.

The function also receives an int `k`; the function will do `k` times a `ceil(num(i)/2)` operation, where `i` should be the `max(list)` in order to get the minimum sum.

I am trying to improve the speed of the results for large lists, but I cant use `numpy`. so for list of 7,20,10 and k=4 results = 14

```
def minmin(list, k):
    for i in range(k):
        maxind = list.index(max(list))
        maxnum = math.ceil(list[maxind] / 2)
        list[maxind] = maxnum

    return sum(list)
```

Comment: could you elaborate, what you're trying to do? Also, perhaps with some examples?

Comment: i want to have a sum of an array that will be the minimum sum possible from all the outcome. this can be achieved as far as i know by looking for the max and k it.take for exp array = [20, 7, 50], with k=4 times of ceil(i/2) i should get minimum sum of 24.

Comment: It is not clear but consider using list comprehension instead of that `for` loop

Comment: @DeusRex you should edit that into the question itself. I am afraid it's still very unclear for me. The "minimum sum" term is almost definitely not the right term for this, where is this ceil and k and other stuff coming from? What is all this supposed to mean anyways?

Comment: Still not clear whay you are trying to achieve here and I think it is not clear to you either

Comment: @DeusRex how many items in the list are expected? Are they `float`s or `int`s ?

Comment: @DeusRex and what are the expected values `k` ?

Comment: @ Ralf the list could reach thousand of items  of the type int.

Comment: @sebastian it an exercise for beginners, needs to minimize the sum of an input to reach the lowest possible outcome of sum(list) and most importantly in the fastest computational way.

Answer (score 0):

Given your explanations and restrictions, there is not much that could by improved; you are already using `list.index()` and `max()`, taken all the advantage of built-in C implementations.

The only thing that makes a small difference could be the assignment to temp vairables and the call to `math.ceil()`; read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299093/how-to-perform-ceiling-division-in-integer-arithmetic) for alternatives to `ceil()`.

Another possibility is to sort the list in descending order so the search finds elements quicker.

Here is a slightly improved version; `f1` is your version, the other is my proposal.

```
def f1(input_list, repetitions):
    input_list = list(input_list)

    for _ in range(repetitions):
        idx = input_list.index(max(input_list))
        new_num = math.ceil(input_list[idx] / 2)
        input_list[idx] = new_num

    return sum(input_list)


def f2(input_list, repetitions):
    input_list = list(input_list)
    input_list.sort(reverse=True)

    for _ in range(repetitions):
        idx = input_list.index(max(input_list))
        input_list[idx] = ((input_list[idx] + 1) // 2)

    return sum(input_list)
```

The code to compare durations and assure that the results are the same:

```
import random
import timeit

for exp_n in range(2, 5):
    n = 10**exp_n
    numbers = [random.randint(1, 9999) for _ in range(n)]

    for exp_k in range(2, 5):
        k = 10**exp_k

        t1 = timeit.timeit(
            'f(numbers, k)', 'from __main__ import numbers, k, f1 as f',
            number=10)
        t2 = timeit.timeit(
            'f(numbers, k)', 'from __main__ import numbers, k, f2 as f',
            number=10)

        print('n {:10,d} | k {:10,d} | {:10.4f} | {:10.4f} | best f{}'.format(
            n, k, t1, t2, '1' if t1 < t2 else '2'))
        assert f1(numbers, k) == f2(numbers, k)
```

The results are (using `Python 3.6` on `Ubuntu`):

```
n        100 | k        100 |     0.0027 |     0.0025 | best f2
n        100 | k      1,000 |     0.0280 |     0.0251 | best f2
n        100 | k     10,000 |     0.2097 |     0.1872 | best f2
n      1,000 | k        100 |     0.0232 |     0.0190 | best f2
n      1,000 | k      1,000 |     0.2295 |     0.2009 | best f2
n      1,000 | k     10,000 |     2.2607 |     2.1653 | best f2
n     10,000 | k        100 |     0.2139 |     0.1903 | best f2
n     10,000 | k      1,000 |     2.1379 |     1.6530 | best f2
n     10,000 | k     10,000 |    21.3588 |    18.8767 | best f2
```

As you can see, the sorting in reverse order does help.

Comment: thanks for the effort, still i learn a thing or two from your code.

Comment: i have some unbaked thought.... maybe split the list to two and compare one time their max or better yet their ceil(max/2) so for the at least next iteration the max will run on half of the list... is that make some sense. do you have any idea to implement it better.

Comment: @DeusRex I edited my answer; if you sort the list first in descending order, then the speed improves because the bigger elements are at the beggining of the list and the search `.index()` exits earlier