# Preserving id columns in dataframe after applying assign and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file containing different foetal ultrasound measurements. The measurements are collected at different points during pregnancy, like so:

```
PregnancyID MotherID    gestationalAgeInWeeks  abdomCirc
0           0           14                     150
0           0           21                     200
1           1           20                     294
1           1           25                     315
1           1           30                     350
2           2           8                      170
2           2           9                      180
2           2           18                     NaN
```

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65109630/7373787) to a previous questions I had asked, I used this code to summarise the ultrasound measurements using the maximum measurement recorded in a single trimester (13 weeks):

```py
(df.assign(tm = (df['gestationalAgeInWeeks']+ 13 - 1 )// 13))
    .drop(columns = 'gestationalAgeInWeeks')
    .groupby(['MotherID', 'PregnancyID','tm'])
    .agg('max')
    .unstack()
    )
```

This results in the following output:

```
     tm                    1      2     3
MotherID    PregnancyID         
0           0              NaN    200.0 NaN
1           1              NaN    294.0 350.0
2           2              180.0  NaN   NaN
```

However, MotherID and PregnancyID no longer appear as columns in the output of df.info(). Similarly, when I output the dataframe to a csv file, I only get columns 1,2 and 3. The id columns only appear when running df.head() as can be seen in the dataframe above.

I need to preserve the id columns as I want to use them to merge this dataframe with another one using the ids. Therefore, my question is, how do I preserve these id columns as part of my dataframe after running the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain that with `reset_index`:

```
(df.assign(tm = (df['gestationalAgeInWeeks']+ 13 - 1 )// 13)
#    .drop(columns = 'gestationalAgeInWeeks')                 # don't need this
    .groupby(['MotherID', 'PregnancyID','tm'])['abdomCirc']   # change here 
    .max().add_prefix('abdomCirc_')                           # here
    .unstack()
    .reset_index()                                            # and here
    )
```

Or a more friendly version with `pivot_table`:

```
(df.assign(tm = (df['gestationalAgeInWeeks']+ 13 - 1 )// 13)
    .pivot_table(index= ['MotherID', 'PregnancyID'], columns='tm',
                 values= 'abdomCirc', aggfunc='max')
    .add_prefix('abdomCirc_')                        # remove this if you don't want the prefix
    .reset_index()
    )
```

Output:

```
tm     MotherID  PregnancyID  abdomCirc_1  abdomCirc_2  abdomCirc_3
0   abdomCirc_0  abdomCirc_0          NaN        200.0          NaN
1   abdomCirc_1  abdomCirc_1          NaN        315.0        350.0
2   abdomCirc_2  abdomCirc_2        180.0          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple! Been trying to figure this out for the past few days! Thank you!